# Как прочитать и применить файл .gitignore из кода C++?

Tags: c++, gitignore

Я пишу на C++ приложение для синхронизации файлов между двумя директориями. В синхронизируемых директориях могут быть репозиториии git, которые содержат файлы .gitignore. Я хочу сделать так, чтобы моё приложение читало эти файлы .gitignore и при синхронизации игнорировало те же файлы, что и git. [Формат паттернов .gitignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format) не простой и быстро и надёжно реализовать его самостоятельно не получится. Поэтому хотелось бы найти готовую библиотеку, которая бы могла прочитать файл .gitignore, а затем определить нужно ли игнорировать определенный файл или нет. Есть библиотека [libgit2](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2), но она рассчитана на полноценную работу с репозиториями git. Есть опасения, что она будет медленно работать и потреблять много памяти.

Может быть существует какая-нибудь готовая библиотека, которая позволяет только читать файлы .gitignore, без необходимости читать другие файлы репозитория?

Так же подойдёт библиотека, которая преобразует паттерны .gitignore (со звездочками*) в регулярные выражения.

Существуют ли подобные библиотеки?

Comment: Если файл добавлен в .gitignore, то это значит, что гит будет игнорировать *изменения* в этом файле. А текущее состояние добавленных туда файлов может быть уже сохранено в репозиторий и потому подлежать копированию. А еще паттерны .gitignore являются регулярными выражениями.

Comment: Опасения напрасны, libgit2 супербыстрая и суперэкономная. А еще, чтобы не разбираться с ней, можно использовать непосредственно git чтобы получить список игнорируемых файлов (есть специальные ключики для этого).

Comment: @user7860670 Вот цитата из документации: "An asterisk "*" matches anything except a slash. The character "?" matches any one character except "/".". Как это может быть регулярным выражением? В регулярных выражениях * и ? имеют другой смысл.

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan Спасибо за совет, попробую.

Comment: Регулярные выражения - это просто нотации для разбора тестов на регулярных языках. Смысл * и ? в регулярных выражениях произвольный. Возможно вы подразумевали, что смысл * и ? отличается в некой другой конкретной реализации, например в pcre, или что вы привыкли использовать, но это уже другая история.

Comment: @user7860670 Нет, регулярные выражения - это вполне конкретный язык. Как C++ или SQL. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, вот такие ключи генерируют список игнорируемых файлов по .gitignore: `git.exe clean -Xdfn`